# a countable family of continuous functions separating disjoint closed sets

Tags: general-topology

I am wondering if there exists a countable family of continuous functions separating DISJOINT CLOSED SETS in a normal second countable space.
I know there exists a a countable family of continuous functions separating POINT and CLOSED SETS. But I have no idea on how to generalize it to separation of disjoint closed sets. I feel like this is not possible, since it is somehow too nice.

Any suggestion or counter example is appreciated.

Comment: take the integers. The power set is uncountable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily.

Let $X$ be a countably infinite space with the discrete topology (e.g. $X$ is the integers). Every way you partition $X$ into two disjoint non-empty sets, they are closed. If $P$ is the power set of $X$ then for every $A\in P$ you need a function $f_A$ separating $A$ from $X\setminus A$. You need different functions for different $A$'s (more precisely, if $B\not=A$ and $B\not=X\setminus A$ then $f_A$ and $f_B$ must be different). Hence you need $|P|=2^{\aleph_0}$ many functions in your separating family.